# How to get the members of the clusters instead of index in igraph

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, igraph

I have applied the Leiden algorithm to the graph and wanted to retrieve the actual data of each clustered index. Present I am having 12 clusters and am trying to take first index data,so that I can convert id into names in order to cross-check the data.

```
leid1 = G.community_leiden(objective_function="modularity", weights='weight_cosine',
                                      n_iterations=500)
leid2 = G.modularity(leid1, weights='weight_cosine')
```

Now when I am trying to get the members of the cluster with index 0. I am getting the index of the result where as I need actual data of the cluster. As I am new to igraph and Leiden, can anyone let me know where actually I am missing.

My actual data looks like this

```
Clustering with 4875 elements and 9 clusters
[0] 7.0, 21.0, 22.0, 34.0, 65.0, 78.0, 96.0, 178.0, 182.0, 954182.0, 954184.0,
    954188.0, 954189.0, 954194.0, 954195.0, 954196.0, 954198.0, 954207.0,
    954210.0, 954213.0, 954215.0, 954216.0, 954218.0, 954223.0, 954225.0,....
```

```
print (leid1[0])
```

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, ..
```

But I need to retrieve the actual data instead of the index .

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "the actual data"? As you already noted, you have the node indices. You can access the vertex sequence by doing for example `G.vs[leid1[0]]`, and you can then retrieve a specific vertex attribute, e.g. `'name'`, like `G.vs[leid1[0]]['name']`. But perhaps you have the data stored elsewhere, not inside the graph `G`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My data is stored in G and actual data indicates the elements of the cluster. By using the G.vs[leid1[0]]['name'] I am able to retrieve the vertex attribute now. I am trying to do a hierarchical clustering, so I have started searching but ended up with a subgraph method which is provided in API, so is there any way I can do clustering by taking the result of leid1 as input and iterating it 3 times.

Comment: OK, I've turned my comment into an answer then. The hierarchical clustering is probably better discussed separately in another question. In fact, it might be more convenient to discuss this on the `igraph` forum at https://igraph.discourse.group/.

Comment: Thanks. I will post my question in the above forum.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noted, you have the node indices available in `leid1[c]` for community number `c`. You can access the vertex sequence by doing for example `G.vs[leid1[c]]`, and you can then retrieve a specific vertex attribute, e.g. `'name'`, like `G.vs[leid1[c]]['name']`.